# How do I use a pointer to alter a variable after declaration

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following array:

```
uint8_t cmd_length;
uint8_t ctr = 0;
uint8_t hdr[2] = {cmd_length, ctr};
```

Now I want to alter cmd_length, and have the change made to hdr, without having to write hdr[0] = cmd_length again. I guess this would be possible using pointers, but I don't know how.
Thanks

Comment: You should get a compile warning for this code, you are using `cmd_length` uninitiated.  The array consists of one copied trash byte and 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question leaves me with some doubts I correctly understand what you want.
My best guess is you are trying to achieve something like this:

```
int main()
{
    int ctr = 0;
    //replace 42 with what you want cmd_length to be
    int hdr[2] = {42, ctr};
    int *cmd_length = &hdr[0];
    printf("%d \n",*cmd_length);

    *cmd_length = 99;
    printf("%d \n",hdr[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Beware cmd_length is not an `int` anymore but a pointer to an `int` (it"s type is `int*`). (Or uint8_t* in your case)

The output is:

```
42
99
```

Comment: You should read a tutorial or two about pointers anyways though. (I should probably do that too again)